# Struggling to reach answer with algebraic fractions

Tags: polynomials, fractions

The question is $$\frac{2x^3-x^{-3}}{x^3}$$

and the answer is $$2-x^{-6}$$

I have been trying but cannot get to the correct answer using the methods I know. If anyone can explain to me how to do it I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Hint: rewrite it as $(2 x^3 - x^{-3}) \cdot x^{-3}$.

Comment: Thank you this method is actually my favourite, very efficient and who doesn't love getting marks in an exam for multiplying out fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is clear now:
$$\frac{2x^3-x^{-3}}{x^3} = \frac{2x^3}{x^3} -\frac{x^{-3}}{x^3} = 2 - \frac 1 {x^3}\cdot\frac 1 {x^3} =2 - \frac 1 {x^6}= 2-x^{-6} $$

Comment: I understand the transition from stage 1 to stage two, but not with stage 2 to stage 3, would you possibly be able to go over that area a little more ?

Comment: you can express negative powers as the inverse of the positive power: $x^{-3} = \frac 1 {x^3}$

Comment: Thank you it has clicked now ! couldnt see where the second $$1/x^3$$ came from, but I see it's been re-arranged